# Use map or function to create new columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, mapping, purrr

I have the following code that derives new exchange rates from rates I already have:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(ER_AUD_USD = ER_GBP_USD / ER_GBP_AUD, 
         ER_CAD_USD = ER_GBP_USD / ER_GBP_CAD, 
         ER_EUR_USD = ER_GBP_USD / ER_GBP_EUR
  )
```

I may require more, so I'd like to have a function that creates all the ones I'll need from a list of the currencies. The exchange rates are named appropriately so parts of the name can be fixed.

e.g ER_GBP_USD is GBP/USD so:

GBP/USD ÷ GBP/EUR = <strike>GBP</strike>/USD × EUR/<strike>GBP</strike> = EUR/USD

i.e. ER_***_USD <- ER_GBP_USD / ER_GBP_***

sample exchange rates df:

```
         date ER_GBP_CAD ER_GBP_AUD ER_GBP_EUR
1  2016-01-01       2.02       2.07       1.11
2  2016-02-01       1.99       2.10       1.14
3  2016-03-01       1.91       2.06       1.17
4  2016-04-01       1.87       2.04       1.13
```

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
to_currency <- 'USD'
from_currency <- c('AUD', 'EUR','CAD')

paste('ER', to_currency, from_currency, sep = '_') = paste('ER', GBP, to_currency, sep = '_')/paste('ER', from_currency,GBP, sep = '_')
```

but I'm not sure how to map that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your sample data, I will first create a function that creates a new column based on the currency symbols.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

column_new <- function(data, to_cur, from_cur, mid_cur){
  num = sym(paste('ER', mid_cur, to_cur, sep = '_'))
  denom = sym(paste('ER', mid_cur, from_cur, sep = '_'))
  data = data%>%mutate(!!paste('ER', from_cur, to_cur, sep = '_') := !!num/!!denom)
  return(data%>%select(!!sym(paste('ER', from_cur, to_cur, sep = '_'))))
}
```

I will take the sample data you provided.

```
> df
        date ER_GBP_CAD ER_GBP_AUD ER_GBP_EUR
1 2016-01-01       2.02       2.07       1.11
2 2016-02-01       1.99       2.10       1.14
3 2016-03-01       1.91       2.06       1.17
4 2016-04-01       1.87       2.04       1.13
```

And use `purrr::map_dfc` to loop through my currencies to create the new columns

```
> from_currencies = c('AUD','EUR')
> to_currency = 'CAD'
> df%>%bind_cols(map_dfc(from_currencies, ~column_new(df, to_currency, .x, "GBP")))

        date ER_GBP_CAD ER_GBP_AUD ER_GBP_EUR ER_AUD_CAD ER_EUR_CAD
1 2016-01-01       2.02       2.07       1.11  0.9758454   1.819820
2 2016-02-01       1.99       2.10       1.14  0.9476190   1.745614
3 2016-03-01       1.91       2.06       1.17  0.9271845   1.632479
4 2016-04-01       1.87       2.04       1.13  0.9166667   1.654867
```

**Note:** If you want to loop through all currencies as one vector, do this:

```
currencies = c('AUD','EUR', 'CAD')

valid_column = function(x){
  ifelse(is.numeric(x), sum(x) != length(x), TRUE)
}

> df%>%bind_cols(lapply(currencies, function(y) map_dfc(currencies, ~column_new(df,y,.x, "GBP")))%>%bind_cols())%>%select_if(valid_column)

            date ER_GBP_CAD ER_GBP_AUD ER_GBP_EUR ER_EUR_AUD ER_CAD_AUD ER_AUD_EUR
    1 2016-01-01       2.02       2.07       1.11   1.864865   1.024752  0.5362319
    2 2016-02-01       1.99       2.10       1.14   1.842105   1.055276  0.5428571
    3 2016-03-01       1.91       2.06       1.17   1.760684   1.078534  0.5679612
    4 2016-04-01       1.87       2.04       1.13   1.805310   1.090909  0.5539216
      ER_CAD_EUR ER_AUD_CAD ER_EUR_CAD
    1  0.5495050  0.9758454   1.819820
    2  0.5728643  0.9476190   1.745614
    3  0.6125654  0.9271845   1.632479
    4  0.6042781  0.9166667   1.654867
```

You can also use `expand.grid` to loop through all currencies as:

```
currencies = c('AUD','EUR', 'CAD')

par_ams <- expand.grid(from_cur = currencies, to_cur = currencies, KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = F, stringsAsFactors = F)%>%filter(from_cur != to_cur)

> df%>%bind_cols(map2(par_ams$from_cur, par_ams$to_cur, ~column_new(df, .x,.y, 'GBP')))

        date ER_GBP_CAD ER_GBP_AUD ER_GBP_EUR ER_AUD_EUR ER_AUD_CAD ER_EUR_AUD
1 2016-01-01       2.02       2.07       1.11  0.5362319  0.9758454   1.864865
2 2016-02-01       1.99       2.10       1.14  0.5428571  0.9476190   1.842105
3 2016-03-01       1.91       2.06       1.17  0.5679612  0.9271845   1.760684
4 2016-04-01       1.87       2.04       1.13  0.5539216  0.9166667   1.805310
  ER_EUR_CAD ER_CAD_AUD ER_CAD_EUR
1   1.819820   1.024752  0.5495050
2   1.745614   1.055276  0.5728643
3   1.632479   1.078534  0.6125654
4   1.654867   1.090909  0.6042781
```

Comment: Thanks, looping through all of them is a nice touch, I've designed my code to work without the reciprocals, but that may come in handy.

Comment: I'm trying to get the loop through all to work. what is `df_con` supposed to be? I'm getting `object not found`. I think there is a missing line?

Comment: it's supposed to be `valid_column`. I've edited my code.

Comment: I see, presumably that's to deselect the columns that are for/to the same currency (i.e. `ER_USD_USD` which only contain 1s and NAs) I'm now getting the following error:
 `Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols`
I'm not able to find anything on how `valid_column` is supposed to work, do you know of any examples I can find?

Comment: `Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols` could be coming from `sym` in the `column_new` function. Make sure your currencies are all passed to the function as strings e.g. `'USD'`. What I mean is whatever you replace the `currencies` vector with should be a vector of strings and also whatever you replace `"GBP"` with in `~column_new(df,y,.x, "GBP")` is also a string.

Comment: That is the case. If I omit `%>%select_if(valid_column)` it works as required, however it does have redundant columns such as `ER_USD_USD` that only contains `1` or `NA`.

Comment: You can use `expand.grid` instead of the `valid_column` function. I have added that to my answer. Hopefully that should give you what you want.

Comment: Much appreciated, however that gives a different error; `Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"`.

My code works without the select_if, and at this stage the redundant columns aren't an issue. Thanks

Comment: That's strange. The code works. I'm curious as to how you are using it. Can I see your code? That'd be helpful to diagnose what's going on and why you are getting that error

Comment: I've been copying it exactly, only changed the df name:
`my_data %>%
  bind_cols(lapply(currencies, function(y) map_dfc(currencies, ~column_new(my_data,y,.x, "GBP")))%>%bind_cols())`

There is more data, and there are NAs - although even when I remove those rows valid_column has that error. I'm satisfied with what I have, for the time being, though; I don't even need to loop through all the currencies, and the redundant columns are not causing issues.